# auto connection to serial port device with web serial API

Tags: javascript, serial-port, progressive-web-apps, com-port, web-serial-api

what should I do to connect the serial device automatically with the filter device when it plug-in into the computer. I am using web serial API to connect serial devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To open a serial port, first access a `SerialPort` object. For this, you can either prompt the user to select a single serial port by calling `navigator.serial.requestPort()` in response to a user gesture such as touch or mouse click, or pick one from `navigator.serial.getPorts()` which returns a list of serial ports the website has been granted access to.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', async () => {
  // Prompt user to select any serial port.
  const port = await navigator.serial.requestPort();
});
```

```js
// Get all serial ports the user has previously granted the website access to.
const ports = await navigator.serial.getPorts();
```

If a serial port is provided by a USB device then that device may be connected or disconnected from the system. When the website has been granted permission to access a serial port, it should monitor the connect and disconnect events.

```js
navigator.serial.addEventListener("connect", (event) => {
  const port = event.target;
  // TODO: Automatically open port or warn user a port is available.
});
```

Once you have a SerialPort object, calling `port.open()` with the desired baud rate will open the serial port.

```js
// Wait for the serial port to open.
await port.open({ baudRate: 9600 });
```

Source: https://web.dev/serial/

Comment: thank you very much! now I connect the device automatically. great!!

Comment: I am getting event.target with all the handlers set to null.
It was all working fine till base fw change of the microcontroller.